# Trying to delete Orgunit in Admin Directory API always returns 404

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-apis-explorer

Same problem whether I try the API Explorer https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits/delete#try-it or when using the .NET API.

I have a simple integration test that creates a new Orgunit + User under that orgunit.

Then I do this:

1. List all users that match that orgunit path
2. Delete them successfully
3. Try to delete the orgunit itself => 404

I know the orgunit is still there.  I can go into API Explorer and list it here https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/orgunits/list

[image]

If I try to delete it now in API Explorer, no such luck.  I also tried using my root OU's real customer id (instead of my_customer).  Still no luck.

[image]

The *only* way I can delete this orgunit is through the admin console.

[image]

This succeeds -- there were no sub-orgs or users underneath this org, or it would have failed.

[image]

**Why can I not delete the Orgunit through the API or API Explorer?**

Comment: Did you verify if you provided the correct customerId during deletion? Can you try a specific customerId not my_customer for debugging purposes?

Comment: Yes, I verified the right "C" customerId.  Tried literally everything.  I am absolutely confident that this API does not work.  I am not the only person that has filed this.  A couple other SO links, and there is an issue in Google's issue tracker which I upvoted.  Just tough to believe it has been broken for this long and *no-one* has addressed it?  I must be one of the few people to actually try to use it, but that seems impossible given their scale.

Comment: Alright, can you provide the issue tracker link so other devs might see it.

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63418725

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a list of OU's with the following Google Apps Script you can embed in a Google Sheets document.

- You need admin privileges to run the script.
- The script points to an active Google Sheet where you have two sheets: **OrgUnits** and **Log**.
- The sheet named OrgUnits has two columns: one for **orgUnitPath** and another
  for **orgUnitId**.
- Your customer id is stored in the variable **CUSTOMER_ID**.
- Warning, eventually you get errors related with "Request rate higher
  than configured", just isolate the cases and retry them.

Here is the script:

```html
function DeleteOrgUnits(){
  var inputSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("OrgUnits");
  var outputSheetLog = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Log");  
  var dataValues =   inputSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var i, err, errObj;
  var orgUnit, orgUnitItem, orgUnitId = [], orgUnitPath;
  var customerId = CUSTOMER_ID;
  
  outputSheetLog.getDataRange().clear();


  if (dataValues){
    for ( i in dataValues ){
      orgUnit = dataValues[ i ];
      orgUnitPath = orgUnit[ 0 ];
      orgUnitId = orgUnit[ 1 ];
      if (orgUnitPath.length > 0 ){
        err = false;
        try { 
          orgUnitItem = AdminDirectory.Orgunits.remove(customerId, orgUnitId);
        } catch(e){ err = true; errObj = e; };
        if (err)
          outputSheetLog.appendRow([orgUnitPath, 'Error', orgUnitItem, errObj.message ]); 
        else
          outputSheetLog.appendRow([orgUnitPath, 'Deleted', orgUnitItem ]);
      }
    }
    outputSheetLog.appendRow(['Done!']);
  } else {
    outputSheetLog.appendRow(['No Data!']);
  }
}
```